# Minecraft: Using /execute to detect if a Bottle O' Enchanting has been thrown

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating an adventure map for Minecraft and I need to use the /execute command with command blocks to detect when a player has thrown a Bottle O' Enchanting (Exp Bottle). If that has happened, the command teleports the player to the coordinates `0 0 0`.

I tried the following command but it didn't work: `/execute @e[type=ThrownExpBottle] ~ ~ ~ tp @p 0 0 0`

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when we have a problem where someone is stuck with something they're trying to get working. You get targeted answers for the specific part you're stuck, and Arqade gets more useful questions. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank I tried the following command but it didn't work: `/execute @e[type=ThrownExpBottle] ~ ~ ~ tp @p 0 0 0`

Answer (score 4):

Your command is working perfectly fine. Make sure it runs on a clock!

It has a couple flaws though:

- **not multiplayer friendly**: You would teleport every player, once a
  bottle is in the air
- **suspended player**: The player will not
  be able to move until the bottle hits the ground, as you're constantly teleporting him. This is especially bad if you happen to throw a bottle down a high cliff.

But here is an alternative solution, that is more reliable and multiplayer friendly!
The first thing you need to do, is to set up a scoreboard achievement: (type this in chat)

```
/scoreboard objectives add ExpThrown stat.useItem.minecraft.experience_bottle
```

This will count the number of times a player has thrown an experience bottle.
The next thing you want to do is to build a clock that activates a command block with the following command:

```
tp @a[score_ExpThrown_min=1] x y z
```

That is going to teleport all the players that have thrown an experience bottle to the specified coordinates (replace x, y and z).
Now, place a comparator facing away from that command block, into a new one with this command:

```
scoreboard players set @a[score_ExpThrown_min=1] ExpThrown 0
```

That will reset the objective, so that you only get teleported once.

Comment: I don't know why, but this didn't seem to work. Neither of the command blocks had any output. I try to throw a bottle but I don't get teleported anywhere. (The coordinates are ~ ~5 ~)

Comment: Are you sure, that you have the first command block running on a clock? You can test that by typing *say hello* into it. If it spams your chat, then it's working.

Comment: I'm completely sure It's running on a clock. I build a simple comparator clock.

Comment: Hmm... What version are you using? If you upload your world somewhere I'll look into it.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.8. If you'll wait a second I'll upload it somewhere

Comment: I uploaded it to MediaFire: [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rvt6o888b8q3o8k/Redstone_Testing.zip)

Comment: Alright, so somehow the clock is not working :/ Try replacing it with a hopperclock.

Comment: OK, I'll do that later.

Comment: If the comparator clock isn't working, try movig it further away from the command block. Comparator loops fluctuate from *very low* to maximum output, which means the command block will have to be at least 3 blocks away from the comparator